# Swift appended items are not saved

Tags: arrays, swift, append

Here, I declare myArray.

```
class AcikIlanlarViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var myArray: [String] = []
```

Here, I call the function loadPage which modifies the array.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        loadPage()
        //when printed here myArray is nil
    ...
    func loadPage() {
    ...
         Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .validate { request, response, data in
    ...
         let databases = try  JSONDecoder().decode(responseData.self,from: json)
    ...
         for i in 0...databases.orders.count-1 {
            myArray.append(databases.orders[i].header!)
        }

    // when printed here I see the append has worked and myArray is not empty
    }
```

As explained in comments, in viewDidLoad I call loadPage that appends certain stuff in myArray. Just after the append, I can see appended items. However, in viewDidLoad, just after the call to loadPage, myArray turns out to be empty. Why it is not saved?

Comment: `func loadPage()` is that doing an async call?

Comment: You are forgetting your `super.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: post **loadPage** full code ......

Comment: @Larme I didn't do such a thing on purpose. Is it default? How should I prevent it? I assume the code flows like C code. There is a get request with Alamofire and parsing the json in it if that's the issue.

Comment: Do you call any web service that gets the orders ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yeah. Is that the issue?

Comment: yes , it is ...

Comment: @Sh_Khan any idea how to prevent it?

Comment: It's Alamofire, therefore to 100% an async problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reload the table after the for loop

```
for i in 0...databases.orders.count-1 {
   myArray.append(databases.orders[i].header!)
}       
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you! @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 2):

`loadPage()` calls an asynchronous method, so the func will finish before the operation is completed. Mostly, `func`s that call async methods should have a completion handler…

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    loadPage {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func loadPage(completion: () -> Void) {

     Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate { request, response, data in

         let databases = try  JSONDecoder().decode(responseData.self,from: json)

         for i in 0...databases.orders.count-1 {
            myArray.append(databases.orders[i].header!)
        }

        completion()
    }
}
```